# Count the pairs of two columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c("google", "yahoo", "google", "yahoo", "google"), 
                 var2 = c("price1","price1","price1","price1","price2"))
```

I want to count the frequency of pair of the two columns. Here an expected output:

```
df_output <- data.frame(var1 = c("google","google","yahoo","yahoo"), 
                        var2 = c("price1","price2","price1","price2"), count = c(2,1,2,0))
df_output
#      var1   var2 count
# 1 google price1     2
# 2 google price2     1
# 3  yahoo price1     2
# 4  yahoo price2     0
```

How can I make it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base R solution:

```
as.data.frame(table(df$var1, df$var2))
#     Var1   Var2 Freq
# 1 google price1    2
# 2  yahoo price1    2
# 3 google price2    1
# 4  yahoo price2    0
```

Answer (score 4):

One `tidyverse` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 count(var1, var2) %>%
 complete(var1, nesting(var2), fill = list(n = 0))

  var1   var2       n
  <fct>  <fct>  <dbl>
1 google price1     2
2 google price2     1
3 yahoo  price1     2
4 yahoo  price2     0
```

Here it counts per "var1" and "var2" and then generates the missing combinations, filling them with 0.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dcast` and `melt`

```
> as.data.frame(melt(dcast(df,var1~var2)))
```

**OR**

If you have many columns, then pass names as a vector-

```
> var_select = c("var1", "var2")
> as.data.frame(table(subset(df, select = var_select)))

   var1   var2  Freq
1 google price1    2
2  yahoo price1    2
3 google price2    1
4  yahoo price2    0
```

**Note**- Second solution is based on `table` function which was provided by @thothal